# $\int f=0$ implies $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be nonnegative and measurable. Show that $\int f =0$ implies $f=0$ almost everywhere (except possibly on a set of measure zero).

My thoughts. Take a set E with $m(E) \neq 0$. Suppose $f \neq 0$ on E. That means $\int_E f \neq 0$. Since $f$ is nonnegative this implies $\int f >0$. That contradicts the given information, so $f$ must be 0 almost everywhere.

Comment: Your proof works, but it sounds like you are saying that  "$f\neq 0$ on $E$' implies '$\int_E f \neq 0.$' This turns out to be true with your assumptions, but is false in general. A better way to word your argument might be: $${}$$
"Assume $f$ is nonnegative and measurable with $\int f =0$. Choose any $E$ with positive measure, and suppose we were to find that along all of $E$,  $f \neq 0.$. Then since $f$ is nonnegative, $\int_E f>0$. Also since $f$ is nonnegative, $\int f > \int_E f > 0$ which is a contradiction, so any such set $E$ must have zero measure."

Comment: @chris, I think your proof is actually problematic, because there is no reason why $\int f > 0$ except by the answer given below. (That's where my proof broke down and how I ended up at this post actually!)

Answer (score 7):

Let $E_n = \{x | f(x) > {1 \over n} \}$, then $E = \cup_n E_n = \{x | f(x) > 0 \}$.

Hence if $\mu (E) >0$ then there is some $n$ such that $\mu (E_n) >0$ and hence
$\int f \ge \int f 1_{E_n} \ge {1 \over n} \mu (E_n) >0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Where did the $f 1_{E_n}$ come from?

Comment: The integral of $f$ over $E_n$.

Comment: Can we please give this answer a check mark?

Comment: That said, I think maybe $\mu E$ is a typo? I literally just started doing measure theory this morning (for probability purposes), so that might just be new notation that I've not seen before, but surely it means $\mu(E)$, strictly speaking. (I don't mean to be nitpicky.)

Comment: @TannerStrunk: It is a fairly standard abbreviation (more so in probability, I believe), but I will change it to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: If it's standard, then I'd prefer that you don't change it! Ha... I *want* to know what the abbreviations are if I've never seen them before! (Side note, I like the quotes in your MSE profile. Definitely shared some of the lines with mathematician coworkers!)

Comment: @TannerStrunk: :-). I used the notation without thinking, the bracketed version is more appropriate for the real-analysis tag.

Comment: Why the downvote after almost 6 years?